# need to envelop query to count results

Tags: sql, count, subquery

i have this query:

```
SELECT 
[QUERY1].[py],
[QUERY1].[al],
[QUERY1].[ga],
[QUERY1].[sy],
[QUERY1].[pl]
FROM [tab-Sample] as QUERY1, [tab-Sample]
WHERE [tab-Sample].[py] = [QUERY1].[py] AND
[tab-Sample].[al] <> [QUERY1].[al]
```

I would like to write a query that jsut counts the results of this one, i cannot find where to insert the Count(*) also tried with Over() but im unable to manage this.

Comment: my purpose is to find data entry errors; in my table [al] represent a group and a value of [py] can only belong to the same group, so if i find the same value for [py] and different for [al] ther is an error to be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap everything as a sub selection in the `FROM`. Make sure you name it however (`Total`).

```
COUNT (*) AS Amount FROM
(
SELECT 
[QUERY1].[py],
[QUERY1].[al],
[QUERY1].[ga],
[QUERY1].[sy],
[QUERY1].[pl]
FROM [tab-Sample] as QUERY1, [tab-Sample]
WHERE [tab-Sample].[py] = [QUERY1].[py] AND
[tab-Sample].[al] <> [QUERY1].[al] 
) Total
```

Comment: ty, was forgetting to give a name "Total" i noticed that "AS" is neglectable, that or ther is a function i dont notice in tis query?

Comment: why in COUNT (*) AS Amount you use AS and at the end of the quest you dont specify AS Total?

Comment: You don't need to. In fact in this example you don't even need the first as. `AS` is usually for when you declare a string, but as this is a single word with no string literal characters I don't need the as. It is usually good practice however to wrap them in square brackets. Eg: `SELECT COUNT(*) [Amount] FROM`